# Create AlertDialog while holding a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I'm pretty fresh to this android thing, so i'm a bit confused with some concepts still. What I want to do is, while i'm at my Splash Screen, to show an AlertDialog when the user is not connected to the internet. I've tried to do that in so many ways but I can never hold the Thread and so I always get an exception because the activity closes before the dialog is closed. I have tried to do this with an Handler but no success... Part of my code is here:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

 public void openDialog() {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(R.string.dialogo_net)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Sair",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    Splash.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("Definições",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);           
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            alertDialog.show();
        }

 Handler mHandler = new Handler()
 {
     public void handleMessage(Message msg)
     {
        openDialog();//Display Alert
     }
 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while(logoTimer < 2000){
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                };
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                     (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                 NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
           if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
               //opens the dialog in this case
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
              } else {
                //goes to main activity
                startActivity(new Intent("pt.aeist.mobile.START")); }
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    logoTimer.start();
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread logoTimer = new Thread() 
 {
    public void run(){
        try{
             sleep(2000);
             ConnectivityManager cm =
                 (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
             NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

             if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
            {               
                 mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } else 
            {
            startActivity(new Intent("pt.aeist.mobile.START")); }
            finish();
            } 
        }catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }
};
logoTimer.start();
```

Comment: It still shows up instantelly and then disappears with the exception WindowLeaked

Answer (score 0):

//handle finish() separately.

```
.setNegativeButton("Definições",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);           
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove finish() from all places. And check it.

You have to identify the cases where you want to put finish();